# How to get data sent with WebClient.UploadData

Tags: asp.net, upload

i'm trying to upload some data from an ActiveX control to a webpage. The best way for me to do it is in a byte array through WebClient.UploadData.

I'm having some trouble to find how I can retrieve my data on pageload... There are plenty of examples on how to send the data, but I am yet to find one that shows how to get the data on the web server...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)

Problem solved ;)